# Where are you supposed to purchase Windows Server 2019 RDS CALs?

Tags: windows-server-2019, rds

This seems like a very strange problem to me. I'm trying to get RDS User CALs for Windows Server 2019, but I can't seem to find any official place to purchase them. The Microsoft website only lists CALs for 2022. Other online stores, found by simple Google search, vary wildly in price point and appearance, and I can't figure out a good way to tell legitimate sellers from potential scams.

Windows Server is a staple OS, and 2019 is the second-most-recent version and is still [fully supported](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/windows-server-2019). I can't be the only person who needs RDS user CALs. So where do people buy them?

Answer (score 1):

RDS CALS are generally "backward compatible" in that a Server 2022 RDS CAL is valid for a Server 2019 RDS host (and probably also for Server 2016, Server 2012 R2, etc.). While I can't find Microsoft's specific article stating as much, it's a safe bet that you can purchase Server 2022 CALS, install them on a Server 2022 RDS License Server, and use them for your Server 2019 RDS hosts.

As for where to buy them; use a known reputable reseller like Ingram Micro, CDW, etc. or purchase them directly from Microsoft.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/d/windows-remote-desktop-server-cal-2022/dg7gmgf0d7hx

Comment: [This doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/rds-client-access-license) from Microsoft does confirm that RDS CALs should be backwards compatible as far as assignment/distribution to Session Hosts. Unfortunately, as you mentioned, they do require a contemporary License Server to host them. Using 2022 CALs would require me to set up and pay to run an entire additional Windows Server running 2022 just for RDS licensing. Not really a great solution, but maybe the only "official" one.

Comment: Right. That's the rub. A 2019 RDS license server can't manage Server 2022 RDS Cals.